# python exe to run on windows 8 without requireing to run as administrator

Tags: python, windows, windows-8

I had been working on python project which is a console base application
I have created its setup with py2exe on windows 7 32 bit

and I have tried it on windows 7 it is working without requiring the need to run it is administrator

I want to run the same exe on windows 8 64 bit but it always ask for running as administrator and administrator password is there any way to create a python exe which might not ask to run as administrator  and run on windows 8 64 bit

python script contains certain libraries such as pywinusb,MySQLdb and other

Comment: does your script run any command related to the OS system? something like modifying files. I think that because Windows 8 is more secure and it requires you the access rights to process something.

Comment: no it does not it just interacts with the usb  device connected to the system

Comment: Try making a simple console base application (like print a log) and run again.